# in Windows mobile, how to identify key or screen press?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

in Windows mobile, how to identify key press

or screen press ?

in any screen of my program and in any time, even if i not in any textbox focus ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement an IMessageFilter, then do Application.AddMessageFilter(myFilter);

In the message filter, look for WM_MOUSEUP messages (you'll have to search for that and define a constant for it). Then you can use Cursor.CurrentPosition to work out where the mouse was.

For keys, handle:

```
WM_KEYUP and WM_SYSKEYUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott's on the right track.  You need an IMessageFilter.  Unfortunately the CF doesn't support them, nor does Application have an AddMessageFilter method.

The [Smart Device Framework](http://smartdeviceframework.com), however, does have an IMessageFilter, and its Application2 class does support AddMessageFilter.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Compact Framework Team created a sample of how to subclass controls.
You can use the WndProcHooker class to hook event handlers to WM_* events on a control.

http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/20/420551.aspx